# select data from multiple tables in one mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables

1 Policies

```
 | date       | policy_No  | client_no | premium | policy_type   |
 | 2019-01-23 | 10002      |  1570     | 4000    | New policy    |
 | 2019-03-15 | 10003      |  1570     | 16000   | Renewal policy|
```

2 Endorsements

```
  |date       |client_no | policy_no| premium| endorsement_type|
  |2019-02-17 |  1570    |  10002   | 2000   | Debit
  |2019-03-17 |  1570    |  10003   | -4000  | Credit
```

3 Payment

```
  | date      | client_id | policy_no| amount|
  | 2019-03-16| 1570      | 10003    | 10000 |
```

expected result

```
 |  date      | type              | amount|
 | 2019-01-23 | New Policy        |  4000 |
 | 2019-02-17 | Debit endorsement |  2000 |
 | 2019-03-15 | Renewal policy    | 16000 |
 | 2019-03-16 | Payment           | 10000 |
 | 2019-03-17 | Credit endorsement| -4000 |
```

how do i achieve this in one MySQL query

Comment: Do a [union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) on the 3 tables and `order by date desc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try using a union query here:

```
SELECT date, policy_type AS type, premium AS amount FROM Policies
UNION ALL
SELECT
    date,
    CASE WHEN endorsement_type = 'Debit' THEN 'Debit endorsement'
         WHEN endorsement_type = 'Credit' THEN 'Credit endorsement' END,
    premium
FROM Endorsements
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'Payment', amount FROM Payment
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: I know imitation is the sincerest form of flattery but one of the other answers goes a bit far...

Comment: @Nick Thanks for pointing this out.  Plagiarism = you get downvoted.

Comment: There are differences. So small however that they need explanation to count as own contribution...

Answer (score -1):

your tables have 2 common fields and it's not easy to determine which is serving as the primary key or foreign key. However, to select fields from different tables, You can use `LEFT JOIN` `RIGHT JOIN` `INNER JOIN` or `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

You should read [this post from W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to decide which is the best option for you.

The typical syntax is like
 `SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;`

Answer (score -1):

Hope, all three tables have the foreign key. So, we can able to use JOIN concept also like below code,

```
SELECT * from Policies PS
INNER JOIN Endorsements E ON E.policy_no = PS.policy_no
INNER JOIN Payment P ON P.client_id = PS.client_no
ORDER BY date ASC
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -2):

Try that,

```
SELECT date, policy_type type, premium amount 
FROM Policies
UNION ALL
SELECT date,
    CASE WHEN endorsement_type = 'Debit' THEN 'Debit endorsement'
         WHEN endorsement_type = 'Credit' THEN 'Credit endorsement' 
    END type,
    premium amount
FROM Endorsements
UNION ALL
SELECT date, 'Payment', amount FROM Payment
```

Comment: This is pretty much a word for word copy of the most upvoted answer.

Comment: Please highlight and explain the subtle differences between this and the most upvoted answer. In which way do they provide an additional insight or an improvement?

Comment: It is the opposite of an improvement, because it throws away the `ORDER BY` clause.